# ¿Como puedo borrar una fila de un datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

lo que me gustaría saber es como borrar una fila completa de un datagrid cuando el usuario lo seleccione y de clic en un botón, ya que soy nuevo trabajando con bases de datos 
[image: Interfaz de la aplicación]

Comment: Debes añadir el código de lo que has intentado y explicar cual es el problema que estas teniendo. Por otro lado, "soy nuevo trabajando con bases de datos" me hace plantearme la duda: deseas eliminar la fila de la grilla o de la base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la siguiente manera:

```
DataGridName.Items.RemoveAt(DataGridName.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Eso borra la fila del datagridview, pero no de la base de datos, solo lo aclaro.

Comment: Es correcto Luis.